# Passing state to a child component of another child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm building a KanBan app with ReactJS, and I'm trying to pass state from a parent component to the furthest component in the parent-child tree. I have a Column component within my main App component, and within this Column component there is another component called 'Card'. I want to pass the data the gets added/updated in the state of the App component & successfully display it in the Card component. As its obvious by now, the Card component is the child of the Column component.

I tried doing so with this.props but this only works one level down - with the column component. I thought about declaring a variable and equating to this.props.details.cards, and then setting it as the new state of the column component so that I could pass it again as props to the card component, but I assume this is not best practice.

This is my App Component:

```html
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        columns: [
          {
            name: 'Todos',
            cards: []
          },
          {
            name: 'Onprogress',
            cards: []
          },
          {
            name: 'Done',
            cards: []
          }, 
        ] 
      };
    }; 

    addCard = card => {
      console.log("Adding a Card");
      const cards = { ...this.state.columns.cards };
      const keyDate = `card${Date.now()}`

      cards[keyDate] = card;

      this.setState({
        columns: [
          { 
            name: 'Todos',
            cards: cards
          }
        ] 
      });
    };
    
  render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
   {Object.keys(this.state.columns).map(key => (
      <Column key={key} details={this.state.columns[key]} />
    ))}
    <AddCardForm addCard={this.addCard} />
    </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

This is my Column Component:

```html
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Card from "./Card"


class Column extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="column"> 
            <h1 className="Title">{this.props.details.name}</h1>
                <Card />
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Column;
```

And this is my Card Component:

```html
import React, {Component} from "react";

class Card extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="card">
            <span className="title">I'm a Card!</span>
        </div>  
        );
    }
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: You will render Card component in loop in Column component, right?  And will pass card as props to each Card component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React will only get the properties that are injected into the child component.
Considering we have three component `A` , `B` and `C`.

If we want to pass a prop from `A` to `C` while `B` is in the middle, we do this:

- The `A` component returns the `B` component and passes `someProperty` as follows:

`return <B someProperty={someValue} />`

- Now, in the `B` component we can access the property by calling it `this.props.someProperty` however, it won't be available at the `C` component, if we want to do so, we do the following.

`return <C someProperty={this.props.someProperty} />`

What we did in component `B` is pass the `someProperty` that came from component `A` which we can access in `B` as `this.props.someProperty`, we pass it again the same way to the component `C`..

Read more about this: [Passing props between react component](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-pass-props-to-component/)

Full example as follows:

- Component A:

```
render() {
  return (
    <B someProperty={'someString'} />
  );
}
```

- Component B:

```
render() {
  return (
    <C someProperty={this.props.someProperty} />
  );
}
```

- Compoent C: to access the property `someProperty` for example in the render method

```
render() {
  return (
    <p>{this.props.someProperty}</p>
  );
}
```